# Is there a way to check which routes are matched by a term in a routing map?

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, route-map

I have created a prefix-list and I am using it in a route-map. However, my route-map is not working as I expect it to work.

```
ip prefix-list LIST_A seq 5 permit 10.20.20.0/22 ge 32


route-map A-B-OUT permit 10
  match community COMM_A exact-match
  set community 100:100
route-map A-B-OUT permit 15
  match ip address prefix-list LIST_A
  match community COMM_B exact-match
  set community 100:200
route-map A-B-OUT permit 20
  match community COMM_C exact-match
  set community 100:100
```

I added a new term 15 in between two existing terms. 10.20.20.0/16 is matched by some other term but the more specific routes have to be advertised out differently. So I match those with a prefix list and tag them with a different community. However, when I see route 10.20.20.1/32 on B, it is advertised with community 100:100 and not 100:200. That makes me wonder if it is being matched by a later term.

Is there a way to check with routes are being matched by each term in a route map?

Comment: The first match in an access list or route map wins, and the checking stops. Also, with multiple match statements in a single clause, you must match all the statements for it to set.

Comment: There aren't any terms that should match with my route before my term. Also, both the match statements should match. One matches the community string and other matches the IP prefix.

Comment: Then you need to let us see the full configuration. Obviously, something is wrong with the match statements, but we cannot simply guess about it. You should also include things like the routing table, and anything else we could use to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: As a test have you changed the community being set on the sequence 20 term to see if this is falling all of the way through?

Comment: Actually, I am advertising it correctly! The route was being blocked by the policy on the receiving end. When checked with the keyword "hidden" I was able to see that route. Sorry for the confusion!